# Cursor to Selected not snapping precisely to 3d widget in edit mode

Tags: 3d-cursor

Occasionally the Cursor to Selected does not snap precisely to 3d widget in edit mode.  I typically set Pivot Point > individual origins with success, but I've also tried all pivot point options and 3d cursor is still slightly off from widget.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: In Edit Mode, _Cursor to Selected_ should send the cursor to the median point of the implicitly selected vertices, so it should always be the same as the gizmo when the Pivot is set to 'Median' Is that not happening?

Comment: Oh wow, that worked!  Stupid me I didn't redo Cursor to Selected after changing pivot points.  What's weird is Individual Origins seemed to work on other meshes but is off on this one.  Oh well..thanks!

Comment: So I just changed pivot points without redoing Cursor to Selected and it moved the cursor, so I don't know why it didn't snap to the widget before,